# QR Image on the SSRS report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I have a problem that I want to show a QR Image on the SSRS report using visual studio, the problem is that I created an API and the API return a response which is the URL of the image, how can I call the API and use the URL from the response that came from the API

I saw that I can use code expression for the external URL